# Java random number

Tags: java, random, numbers, generator

Beginner question here:
I tried creating a random number using this code

```
int rand = (int) Math.random()*10;
```

however, i kept receiving 0 as the answer when printing to screen

only after putting parenthesis like so

```
int rand = (int)(Math.random()*10);
```

did the number show properly. 
Can anyone explain the logical reason for this that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
int rand = (int) Math.random()*10;
```

is equivalent to

```
int rand = ((int) Math.random()) * 10;
```

So the value of `Math.random()` is converted to an `int`. Because that value **is between 0 and 1 (1 excluded)** it **is converted** always **to zero**.

So

```
(int) Math.random()*10 -->  ((int) Math.random()) * 10 --> 0 * 10 --> 0
```

Answer (score 5):

When you write `int rand = (int) Math.random()*10`, you're actually writing:

```
int rand = ((int) Math.random()) * 10;
```

Therefore you get 0 because the random number is between 0 and 1, and casting it to an `int` makes it equals to 0.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` returns a `double` number between 0 and 1 exclusive, which means `(int)Math.random()` will always be 0 (since `Math.random() < 1`). In order to perform the multiplication before the cast to int, you must use parentheses as you did.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already explained the issue with your code, so I won't cover this topic here anymore.

This is just a note on the generation of random-numbers:
The recommended way of generating random-numbers in java isn't `Math.random()` , but via the `java.util.Random` class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

To generate a random-number like in the above example, you can use this code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int i = rnd.nextInt(10);
```

, which will produce the same result as your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rand = (int) Math.random()*10;
```

is equivalent to

```
int rand = ((int) Math.random())*10;
```

Considering that Math.random() return a number from 0<=N<1, if you try to cast it you will always get 0, that multiply by 10 is still 0

```
int rand = ((int) Math.random()); -- ALWAYS --> ZERO

0*N ---- ALWAYS ---> ZERO
```